# apache2, debian - web page does not load

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I am beginner in debian system. I have run into problem - on my VirtualBox Debian system I have installed mysql and apache2 (two simple commands, what could go wrong), but after installing apache, the default web page on 192.168.0.100 leads to not found status. I have no permissions to access error.log file. Could somebody advise what is the problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to access it from inside the same machine or from a different machine?

If you're getting that error when you try to access the page from the same system, you should make sure Apache is running:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If you're getting that error when you try to access the page from a different machine, either another VM or the host system or another system entirely, you should make sure it isn't being blocked by the firewall:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

If you can access the web page from a different machine with the firewall stopped, you'll need to add a rule to allow http traffic through, usually on port 80.

UPDATED AFTER CHAT:

Issue ended up being the wrong IP was being used to reach the VM and the Apache2 instance. User determined this himself during investigation.

Comment: I have Debian in Oracle VirtualBox and I want to access it from my browser in my own system (same PC). I have tried restarting, even reinstalling apache, but the default web page on that address does not show.

Comment: Did you check the firewall? What is the status of apache2? /etc/init.d/apach2 status.

Also, FYI, so far as the VM knows, your computer is a different system than it. Can you ping the VM from your PC? The issue could be you don't have the network setup properly for Virtualbox.

Comment: Status: Apache2 is running.
After turning off Windows Firewall the web page has not load. How could I find out if I have network setup properly?

Comment: Did you turn off the firewall on the VM? NOT the PC. The VM has its own firewall that needs to be managed.

Comment: Also, in the VM settings, what is the network adapter attached to? It should be set to Bridged Adapter. (Virtual Box, Right click on VM select Settings, Network, Attached to:)

Comment: Yes, I have bridged adapter. I have not do anything with debian firewall ever, it is required to turning off it?

Comment: Please see the instructions in my solution for turning off the firewall in Debian ^^ and let me know if that works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11006/discussion-between-tom11-and-music2myear)